# How to update parent POM and related children?

Tags: maven, tycho, maven-versions-plugin

First the structure: My parent POM has no references to child modules etc. There is a separate reactor-POM that contains the `<modules>...</modules>` section - and the reactor POM is also a child of the parent POM (the modules listed in the reactor POM inherit from the parent POM).

Last but not least its a Eclipse/Tycho build.

Now, i want to update the version of the whole project. Starting with the parent POM there is the first problem: How can i force the child modules of the parent to update the parent version, if the child modules are declared in a different POM (the reactor)?

Comment: Why do you have no references to child modules in your parent? Why a separate reactor pom? Does not make sense to me...

Comment: The idea behind this structure is to have a separate aggregator. The parent POM maintains dependencies etc only.

Comment: @norb Can't you just use the parent POM as parent of the reactor pom? Then you can use the reactor pom as parent for the modules.

Comment: If you have a parent which contains all the modules then you have an aggregator. Apart from that the parent does not maintain dependencies it should maintain the list of dependencies which are possible via dependencyManagement this is something different..

Comment: @JFMeier thanks for your responses. I merged my parent and aggregator into a single POM in the end. Afterwards, I also found another 'nice' approach by [Robert Reiner](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/display/BLOG/2013/07/22/Using+Aggregate+and+Parent+POMs).

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your answers!